# Can't reference variable on second statement of while loop

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm trying to execute multiple commands on an input, (this is part of a larger attempt, by me, to get all my code onto one line rather than call multiple sh files) but when it comes to the second command, I can't reference the environment variable properly ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r i; do
    echo "Drive $2 - $3 $i"
    echo "$3"
done < drivelist.txt
```

drivelist.txt contains...

```
Port 1  /dev/sdc
Port 2  /dev/sdd
Port 3  /dev/sdb
Port 4  /dev/sda
```

I was hoping for

```
Drive - Port 1 /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc
Drive - Port 2 /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd
Drive - Port 3 /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb
Drive - Port 4 /dev/sda
/dev/sda
```

I'm getting...

```
Drive - Port 1 /dev/sdc

Drive - Port 2 /dev/sdd

Drive - Port 3 /dev/sdb

Drive - Port 4 /dev/sda
```

I've also tried accessing $i in the second echo statement with ${i[2]} and that doesn't work either. However, if I try echo $3 $i then the whole of $i is there, and accessible... I just can't get at the third element.

Comment: `echo "Port 1  /dev/sdc^JPort 2  /dev/sdd^JPort 3  /dev/sdb^JPort 4  /dev/sda"| awk '{printf( "Drive -- %s\n%s\n", $0,
$NF)}'` produces the output you have specified. As far as your current code, look for other examples of how `while read var1 var2 ... varN` work. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still getting used to stackoverflow and this sort of thing.

Comment: I was actually trying to get over the variable in the second part. I didn't want to combine them. The echo statements are misleading so I put a bad example. My apologies.

Comment: Where do the values for `$2` and `$3` come from? Your loop could not possibly produce these results.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `awk '{ print "Drive", $2, "-", $3, $0; print $3 }' drivelist.txt` (where obviously I had to guess what's in the file; and separately, [fix any DOS line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)).

Comment: This is what I was trying to do. Print the date and then go through all devices, cut them down to the unique devices, sorted by port (because /dev/sda isn't necessarily on sata port 1) and then query smartctl against the device name and isolate important errors...

Comment: date > /root/health.txt && for i in /dev/disk/by-path/*;do [[ ! "$i" =~ '-part[0-9]+$' ]] && echo "Port $(basename "$i"|grep -Po '(?<=ata-)[0-9]+') $(readlink -f "$i")" | sed -n '/^.*sd[a-d][0-9]/!p';done | sort -u | while read i ; do echo Drive $2 - $3 $i >> /root/health.txt && smartctl -a $(cut -d " " -f 3 <<< $i) | grep -ie "reallocated_" -ie "error" -ie "fail" -ie "bad" | grep -ie "old_age" -ie "pre-fail" | grep -iv "spin" | grep -iv "helium" | sed -n '/^.* 0$/!p' | sed -n '/^.*0\/0$/!p' >> /root/health.txt >> /root/health.txt ; done

Comment: That comment actually works. (when run as root) I'm rapidly finding out what you mean about formatting, though. I've had to re-edit a number of times and although I'm using Linux and associated editors, I'm not sure how DOS line endings got in anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The people who invented shell (a tool to create/destroy files/processes and sequence calls to other tools) also invented awk (a general purpose tool to manipulate text) for shell to call when text needs to be manipulated:

```
$ awk '{print "Drive -", $0 ORS $NF}' drivelist.txt
Drive - Port 1  /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc
Drive - Port 2  /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd
Drive - Port 3  /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb
Drive - Port 4  /dev/sda
/dev/sda
```

See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

As for why you aren't seeing the contents of `$2` and `$3` in your script - you are seeing them but they're empty. `$2` and `$3` in a shell script are positional parameters populated with the 2nd and 3rd arguments pass to the currently running shell, nothing to do with a `while-read` loop.

If you **were** going to write a shell loop to read those values, e.g. if you had to call other tools per line read from the file, then it'd be:

```
$ while read -r a b c; do
    printf 'Drive %s - %s %s\n%s\n' "$a" "$b" "$c" "$c"
done < drivelist.txt
Drive Port - 1 /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc
Drive Port - 2 /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd
Drive Port - 3 /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb
Drive Port - 4 /dev/sda
/dev/sda
```

or:

```
$ while read -ra f; do
    printf 'Drive %s - %s %s\n%s\n' "${f[0]}" "${f[1]}" "${f[2]}" "${f[2]}"
done < drivelist.txt
Drive Port - 1 /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc
Drive Port - 2 /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd
Drive Port - 3 /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb
Drive Port - 4 /dev/sda
/dev/sda
```

or similar.